# Error copying encoded utf-8 text from google sheets to web element text field

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, utf-8

I'm trying to get a text from Google Sheets, which is encoded in UTF-8, and copy it into any text field web element, but selenium throws an error when I try to send_keys to the text field.

I've tried not encoding the UTF-8 text and encoding it and in both situations, I get an error.

```py
post description = 'Science! ✨' # (just an example)
post_description = post_description.encode('utf-8')

driver.get("https://www.editpad.org/")
time.sleep(10)

inputElement = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#text")
inputElement.send_keys(post_description)
```

Here's what I get with the encoding:

```py
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

Here's what I get without the encoding:

```py
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: missing command parameters
```

I've researched this a lot and can't seem to find an obvious solution to copy-pasting utf-8 text from a source to another.

Any ideas?

Comment: Works well. No `UnicodeDecodeError`

Comment: @BlackThunder on what system are you running it?

Comment: I am using Windows 10, with python 3.7.3

Comment: Just for making sure, I am testing with selenium

Comment: @BlackThunder there are many other strings like this one with many other chars. Do you have any idea why some work and others don't?

Comment: Encoding works perfectly for me but looks like selenium can't handle such chars. `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`

Comment: After encoding, this is what I get:  `Science! \xf0\x9f\x94\xad\xf0\x9f\x92\xab\xf0\x9f\x9a\x80\xe2\x9c\xa8`

Comment: I guess the only way then is to copy it to clipboard and paste it by sending CTRL+V? I've tried that with Tkinter as it has clipboard support but I think there's an issue with that method as well because it crashes the browser when I try to paste it. I'll try again and see where exactly it breaks down. I just wanted to make sure it's not my setup or a python or selenium problem.

Comment: @BlackThunder it may work for that exact text but for longer strings with more chars it may not. It's really important for the program to have a reliable way to copy-paste all of the text as I could probably remove those missing bytes otherwise with unicodedata.normalize.